# Firebase Swift - Realtime update does not work when result is filtered by search controller

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, search, uisearchcontroller

I am making an iOS app using Swift and Firebase. The view controller retrieves/observes items and stores them in items array. Item cell has + and - buttons that perform an update on the quantity of the item using its indexPath.

If I use search controller to filter items, I get to store search results in filteredItems array. I am trying to update quantity of these filtered items but they only get to update once when I tap + or - button and does not show the update in search result view (no separate view, I display the filteredItems using data source in the same view). Even if I hit it multiple times, it always updates once.

Once I go back to the regular view by canceling search bar, I see 1 up or down depends on which button I tapped. Does anyone know what might be causing the problem here?

```
class ItemsViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, SortTypeTableViewControllerDelegate, ItemListCellDelegate {
private var items = [Item]()
private var filteredItems = [Item]()

private func retrieveFirebaseData(sortType: ItemSort.SortType, sortOrder: ItemSort.SortOrder) {
guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
  return print("user not logged in")
}

let itemsRef = DatabaseReferenceHelper.usersRef.child(currentUser.uid).child("items")

itemsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: sortType.rawValue).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
  var newItems: [Item] = []

  for item in snapshot.children {
    let item = Item(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
    if self.displayFavoritesOnly == true {
      if item.favorite == true {
        newItems.append(item)
      }
    } else {
      newItems.append(item)
    }
  }

  self.items = sortOrder == .ascending ? newItems : newItems.reversed()
  self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
}

// this is from item cell delegate
func increaseDecreaseQuantity(_ sender: ItemListCell, increment: Bool) {
  guard let tappedIndexPath = collectionView.indexPath(for: sender) else {
    return
  }

  let item: Item
  item = isFiltering() ? filteredItems[tappedIndexPath.item] : items[tappedIndexPath.item]

  let updatedQuantity = increment == true ? item.quantity + 1 : item.quantity - 1

  guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
    return print("user not logged in")
  }

  let itemsRef = DatabaseReferenceHelper.usersRef.child(currentUser.uid).child("items")

  itemsRef.child(item.key).updateChildValues(["quantity": updatedQuantity])

}


// Here's the search logic I learned from Ray Wenderlich
private func searchBarIsEmpty() -> Bool {
  return searchController.searchBar.text?.isEmpty ?? true
}

private func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
  filteredItems = items.filter({$0.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
  collectionView.reloadData()
}

private func isFiltering() -> Bool {
  return searchController.isActive && !searchBarIsEmpty()
}


extension ItemsViewController: UISearchResultsUpdating {

  func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    filterContentForSearchText(searchController.searchBar.text!)
  }
}
```

Comment: With this code, each time an specific item is updated, the entire item list is reloaded. Another option would be to use .childAdded, .childChanged and .childRemoved so when just one item is modified, you can update just that one item in your array.

Comment: @Jay Is that a suggestion to make the code more efficient or a possible fix? I saw a blog post saying specific usage of .childAdded, .childChanged, .childRemoved saves data so I thought of using them as well.

Comment: It was more of a suggestion that would make it a bit cleaner and reduce hits to Firebase and the amount of data being moved around. I am not seeing any glaring code issues that would cause the issue you describe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue. All I did was adding another parameter called "searchText" in retrieveFirebaseData function and use the function in filterContentForSearchText.

Basically, I needed to filter items UNDER observe method like in the code below.

```
private func retrieveFirebaseData(sortType: ItemSort.SortType, sortOrder: ItemSort.SortOrder, searchText: String?) {

  guard let currentUser = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
    return print("user not logged in")
  }


  let itemsRef = DatabaseReferenceHelper.usersRef.child(currentUser.uid).child("items")

  itemsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: sortType.rawValue).observe(.value) { (snapshot) in
    if let searchText = searchText {
      // FILTER HERE
      self.filteredItems = self.items.filter({$0.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
    } else {
      var newItems: [Item] = []
      for item in snapshot.children {
        let item = Item(snapshot: item as! DataSnapshot)
        if self.displayFavoritesOnly == true {
          if item.favorite == true {
            newItems.append(item)
          }
        } else {
          newItems.append(item)
        }
      }        
      self.items = sortOrder == .ascending ? newItems : newItems.reversed()
    }

    self.collectionView.reloadData()
  }
}

private func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
  retrieveFirebaseData(sortType: itemSortType, sortOrder: itemSortOrder, searchText: searchText)
}
```

"filterContentForSearchText" function used to filter items and reload table like this:

```
private func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
  filteredItems = items.filter({$0.title.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())})
  collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reload your collectionView after each + & -. Once you reload your collection view, new updates will be visible.

Comment: I have tried it but it does nothing. Plus, I did not need to reload collection view to realtime update my data when the result is not filtered.